# How to set a function for every element, using forEach in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I'm making an Etch a sketch game in JS.
I have a two questions: 
**1) How to set a function to all elements in grid?**

```js
cellArray.forEach(elem => {
    elem.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    });
});
```

When i change color like that, it's changing for all cells, but when i try with function it's change only the last one, when i mouseover of any of it.

**2) How can i do my grid change size every time when the input.value changed by user, without reloading the page? I think about AJAX, but i'm very new one, so i don't know much.**

```js
let sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch-grid'),
cellArray = [],
input = document.querySelector('.input-skh'),
cellNumber;

cellNumber = input.value;


let colors = {
    blue: function () {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
    },
    white: function () {
        cell.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
    },
    random: function () {
        let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (256)),
            g = Math.floor(Math.random() * (256)),
            b = Math.floor(Math.random() * (256)),
            randomColor = '#' + r.toString(16) + g.toString(16) + b.toString(16);
        cell.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
    }
};

    function buildGrid(){
            sketch.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${cellNumber}, auto)`;
            sketch.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${cellNumber}, auto)`;
            for (let i = 0; i < cellNumber * cellNumber; i++){
              
                cell = document.createElement('div');
                cell.classList.add('cell');
                sketch.appendChild(cell);
                cellArray.push(cell);
            }

    }
    
input.addEventListener('oninput', buildGrid());

  /*let cellNumber = +prompt('The size of sketch is: ');*/

  


  function changeColor(){
    colors.random();
}

cellArray.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('mouseover', changeColor()));
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.sketch-input {
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: lightseagreen;
}
.sketch-input .input-skh {
  width: 300px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: mediumpurple;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: white;
}
.sketch-input label {
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
}

.wrapper-sketch {
  width: 100%;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 20px;
}
.wrapper-sketch #sketch-grid {
  display: grid;
  margin: 10px auto;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
}
.wrapper-sketch #sketch-grid div {
  border: 2px solid crimson;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Etch a sketch</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../templates/main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="sketch-input">
    <label>Choose a size of your sketch:</label>
    <input class="input-skh" type="range" min="3" max="50">

</div>
<div class="wrapper-sketch">
    <div id="sketch-grid"></div>
</div>

<div class="buttons">
    <button class="button__choose-color">Change Color</button>
    <button class="button__reset">RESET</button>
</div>


<script src="../js/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for first question - cellArray - what is the length of it?  Probably it has only 1 element?

Comment: @kurumkan yes you are right, the length is zero, but i don't know what to do with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checkout the fixes in snippet below:

**Minor changes:**

```
cellArray.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('mouseover', () => changeColor(elem)));
```

Register the event handler function instead of calling `changeColor()` function immediately. Also pass in the current `elem` to the function.

```
random: function (elem) {
    let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (256)),
        g = Math.floor(Math.random() * (256)),
        b = Math.floor(Math.random() * (256)),
        randomColor = '#' + r.toString(16) + g.toString(16) + b.toString(16);
    elem.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
}
```

Use the `elem` as the argument/parameter instead of using global `cell` value.

**Expand and see snippet below:**

```js
    let sketch = document.querySelector('#sketch-grid'),
    cellArray = [],
    input = document.querySelector('.input-skh'),
    cellNumber;

    cellNumber = input.value;


    let colors = {
        blue: function () {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
        },
        white: function () {
            cell.style.backgroundColor = 'white';
        },
        random: function (elem) {
            let r = Math.floor(Math.random() * (256)),
                g = Math.floor(Math.random() * (256)),
                b = Math.floor(Math.random() * (256)),
                randomColor = '#' + r.toString(16) + g.toString(16) + b.toString(16);
            elem.style.backgroundColor = randomColor;
        }
    };

        function buildGrid(){
                sketch.style.gridTemplateRows = `repeat(${cellNumber}, auto)`;
                sketch.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${cellNumber}, auto)`;
                for (let i = 0; i < cellNumber * cellNumber; i++){
                  
                    cell = document.createElement('div');
                    cell.classList.add('cell');
                    sketch.appendChild(cell);
                    cellArray.push(cell);
                }

        }
        
    input.addEventListener('oninput', buildGrid());

      /*let cellNumber = +prompt('The size of sketch is: ');*/

      


      function changeColor(elem){
        colors.random(elem);
    }

    cellArray.forEach(elem => elem.addEventListener('mouseover', () => changeColor(elem)));
```

```css
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .sketch-input {
      margin: auto;
      text-align: center;
      background-color: lightseagreen;
    }
    .sketch-input .input-skh {
      width: 300px;
      height: 70px;
      background-color: mediumpurple;
      font-size: 40px;
      color: white;
    }
    .sketch-input label {
      color: white;
      font-size: 35px;
    }

    .wrapper-sketch {
      width: 100%;
      height: 800px;
      background-color: black;
      padding: 20px;
    }
    .wrapper-sketch #sketch-grid {
      display: grid;
      margin: 10px auto;
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
    }
    .wrapper-sketch #sketch-grid div {
      border: 2px solid crimson;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Etch a sketch</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../templates/main.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="sketch-input">
        <label>Choose a size of your sketch:</label>
        <input class="input-skh" type="range" min="3" max="50">

    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-sketch">
        <div id="sketch-grid"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="buttons">
        <button class="button__choose-color">Change Color</button>
        <button class="button__reset">RESET</button>
    </div>


    <script src="../js/app.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```